# New IE windows open in background on restricted computer

Tags: windows, group-policy, internet-explorer

We have a new computer build that is locked down via GPO.  We have locked it down as tight as we can, but now new IE windows that are opened with shortcuts open behind the active window.  I can post the whole list of restrictions if it is necessary, but there are a lot of restrictions.  The machine has a domain account that automatically logs in, that account is the actual AD object that we have locked down.  What restrictions could cause the new windows to not have focus?

I apologize for a question like this, but I had 1 day to build this, and now 2 days to iron out bugs our clinical analysts find.

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea where to find this in GPO, but this behaviour can be curbed in IE by going to (in IE8): Tools > Options > Tabs (group under general) > Settings, and checking "Always open Pop Ups in a new tab".

Comment: There is an actual GPO for this behavior, that only works on IE7 or later, we need to use IE6 because some of the software is only certified one IE6 (sigh).

Comment: Ohh, I see your problem now. Gotta love those IE6 only internal apps (we have one too, thank the lord for VMWare Player)

Comment: Is this a kiosk or are your users all felons? ;)

Comment: Worse, doctors.